# Empty FileUpload Text Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a fileupload controller in my asp.net form.I've to empty the fileupload text using javascript on radiobutton click.

How will we do that.Here's my code...

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbnImage" runat="server" Text="Image" GroupName="a" 
onclick="SetVisibility(this.id)"
```

Javascript goes here

```
function SetVisibility(id) {
        if (id == 'rbnImage') {
            document.getElementById('fupLogo').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('fupLogo').value = '';                
            document.getElementById('txtText').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

    }
```

This code is not working.Its working for textbox.

Comment: Did you see that the id of RadioButton is 'rbnImage' and you ask 'rbnText'?

Comment: Sorry my mistake during asking question.I've corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the value of File upload.

Try this trick:

```
var browse=document.getElementById(control);  
var newbrowse= browse.cloneNode(false);   
browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse ,browse);
```

Comment: Hurray its working fine...Thanks a lot.. Can u explain how fileuploader is getting empty